# Reading RFC822 field from certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I have this certificate:

[image: Windows Certificate]

I need read field "RFC822". I use X509Certificate2 class, but this class don't return this information:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
X509Certificate2 card = GetCertificate();                    

sb.AppendLine(card.FriendlyName);
sb.AppendLine(card.GetCertHashString());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetEffectiveDateString());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetExpirationDateString());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetExpirationDateString());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetFormat());
//sb.AppendLine(card.GetIssuerName());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetKeyAlgorithm());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetKeyAlgorithmParametersString());
//sb.AppendLine(card.GetName());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetPublicKeyString());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetRawCertDataString());
sb.AppendLine(card.GetSerialNumberString());
sb.AppendLine(card.HasPrivateKey.ToString());
sb.AppendLine(card.Issuer);
sb.AppendLine(card.IssuerName.Name);
sb.AppendLine(card.SerialNumber);
sb.AppendLine(card.Subject);
sb.AppendLine(card.SubjectName.Name);
sb.AppendLine(card.Thumbprint);
sb.AppendLine(card.Version.ToString());
```

Can I read RFC822 data from .NET program?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in [Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.extensions.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

You can get bytes of a Subject Alternative Name extension by

```
byte[] subjAltName = cert.Extensions["2.5.29.17"].RawData
```

If you look at these bytes by `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(subjAltName)` you will see email address. But this byte array actually represents an ASN.1 Sequence structure and needs to be decoded properly. As Eugene stated it may be easier to use a third party library which encapsulates complex ASN.1 stuff if you need some deep information inside a certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I find a solution to parse this data using Windows API in: http://www.hanneskoehler.de/2011/03/16/ParseTheSubjectAlternativeNameOfACertificate.aspx